# multi store magento - different domain, same products

Tags: magento, store

friends,

I'm in doubt about the possibility of a configuration with multiple store magento.

I will explain my business:

I have a online store selling jewelry.

What I need:

I want to create micro franchise scheme to expand my shop
I want to provide a copy of my partner shop:

- Different domain
- Same products
- Receive different paypal account
- The seller will only see a list of your customers (independent customers)
- The seller will only see a list of their requests (requests independent)
- The main shop can see everything (requests, customers)

Is that possible?
Is there any technical procedure?
Is there any extension that makes it work so simple in creation of additional stores?

Please help me on how I can do this.

***I have interest in hiring the service of realizing this project.***

Thank you all!

Rodrigo Rodrigues (rodrigopantaneiro # gmail)
Brazil

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible and easy enough to do with the multi-store and store front views.. You will need to edit the httpd.conf file for your domain problem [Magento Multiple Store and Views](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work)

then the login to the admin area for the sellers would be set to only view their customers/items etc. via the roles and permissions on the system.